# Why is the Date does not display

Tags: reactjs

I don't get why my Date doesn't show on the screen while the time does.
If any one can do me a favor to explain to me what is the error or what makes the approached of my logic faulty. I have seen few correction what is different on my logic but they haven't explain what's was the mistake. All they did was just answering using a different logic.
Your answer will help if you tell me what is the problem in this logic of mine not only correct in a different logic but the explanation would be much better.

```
    import React,{Component} from 'react';
    class Timer extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
          this.state={
            Time: "",
            date: "",
          }
      
        this.myTime = this.myTime.bind(this);
        this.myDate = this.myDate.bind(this);

    }// end of constructor

    myTime(){
        const date = new Date();
        this.setState(prevState =>({
            Time: date.toLocaleTimeString(),
           
        }))
    }// end of myTime function

    myDate(){
        const d = new Date();
        this.setState(prevState=>({
            date: d.toLocaleDateString(),
        }))

       
    }//end of myDate function*/

    render(){
        return(
            <div className='WelcomePageCentr'>
              <h1 onLoad={this.myDate}>{this.state.date}</h1>
              <h1 onLoad={setInterval(this.myTime,1000)}>{this.state.Time}</h1>  
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Timer
```

[image: Only The times display but not the date]

Answer (score 0):

getting alot of errors from the onLoad method so i changed it to use componentDidMount

```
class Timer extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state={
        Time: "",
        date: "",
      }
  
    this.myTime = this.myTime.bind(this);
    this.myDate = this.myDate.bind(this);

}// end of constructor

myTime(){
    const date = new Date();
    this.setState(prevState =>({
        Time: date.toLocaleTimeString(),
       
    }))
}// end of myTime function

myDate(){
    const d = new Date();
    this.setState(prevState=>({
        date: d.toLocaleDateString(),
    }))

   
}//end of myDate function*/

componentDidMount() {
  this.myDate()
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.myTime()
  }, 1000);
}
componentWillUnmount(){
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {})
}

render(){
    return(
        <div className='WelcomePageCentr'>
          <h1>{this.state.date}</h1>
          <h1>{this.state.Time}</h1>  
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go. Just add a `componentWillUnmount` is missing and use `cancelInterval(this.interval)`. `this.interval = setInterval(() => {})` to remove the interval on unmount. The problem with `onLoad` is that it is creating an infinite render loop. It runs on load and then the method sets the state, that's causing a re-render and another `onload` and so on. The same issue at the time but there is enough time between re-renders to render it.

Comment: Updated it, Thanks :)